# Docker: How to verify if an overlay network is encrypted

Tags: docker, docker-swarm

Is there any way to check whether an overlay network is actually encrypted?

I know that you can create an encrypted overlay network using

```
docker network create --opt encrypted --driver overlay my-encrypted-network
```

But since you can specify virtually *anything* as driver option (`--opt`) you can easily mistype "encrypted" and docker won't complain.

Let's say I type (notice the typo!)

```
docker network create -d overlay --opt encryptedsd my-encrypted-network
```

Now using `docker network inspect my-encrypted-network` I only get the information of what I typed, but I can't see if the network is actually encrypted.

```
[
    {
        "Name": "my-encrypted-network",
        "Id": "j4jd8dlde9u7rs1crlzbqco4p",
        "Created": "2020-02-01T13:17:39.65392102Z",
        "Scope": "swarm",
        "Driver": "overlay",
        "EnableIPv6": false,
        "IPAM": {
            "Driver": "default",
            "Options": null,
            "Config": [
                {
                    "Subnet": "10.0.4.0/24",
                    "Gateway": "10.0.4.1"
                }
            ]
        },
        "Internal": false,
        "Attachable": false,
        "Ingress": false,
        "ConfigFrom": {
            "Network": ""
        },
        "ConfigOnly": false,
        "Containers": null,
        "Options": {
            "com.docker.network.driver.overlay.vxlanid_list": "4100",
            "encryptedsd": ""
        },
        "Labels": null
    }
]
```

Apart from typos, this does not feel reassuring, since I would really like to know whether encryption is actually enabled instead of just knowing what I typed.

Does anyone know if there is a better way to get a reliable answer?

Answer (score 1):

According to the docs:

> When you enable overlay encryption, Docker creates IPSEC tunnels between all the nodes where tasks are scheduled for services attached to the overlay network. These tunnels also use the AES algorithm in GCM mode and manager nodes automatically rotate the keys every 12 hours.

An approach different to the one you mention (which IMO, is valid), would be to check (e.g. using `netstat`) whether those IPSEC tunnels where created.